# Get 5V output from NodeMCU

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, wifi, nodemcu

I have a sensor that requires used of 5V as input to Vcc. But I dont see any 5V output pins on the NodeMCU 1.0(12E). Is there a way I could get 5V output pins?

Its not a duplicate question. I want a 5V output and not provide 5V input to NODEMCU.

Comment: Its not a duplicate question. I want a 5V output and not provide 5V input to NODEMCU.

Comment: I also did not know the Vin pin could be used for output; read the accepted answer from Majenko.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The `VIN` pin outputs 5V approximately (dependent on USB input voltage) from the NodeMCU board.

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95276/discussion-on-answer-by-tony-gil-get-5v-output-from-nodemcu).

Comment: thank you @VE7JRO!

Comment: On my boards, the Vin pin outputs 4.76V because there's a Schottky diode between Vusb and the Vin pin which drops the voltage (see the [circuit diagram](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-devkit-v1.0/blob/master/NODEMCU_DEVKIT_V1.0.PDF)). This Vin is also quite noisy and is a poor power source for analog circuitry.